# iTunes API for python scripting

Tags: python, itunes, win32com

I'm trying to develop some scripts for iTunes in python and actually i'm having quite a hard time getting the API information.

I'm using the win32com.client module but i would really need to get all the specifications, methods and details.

There are a few examples but I need some extra data......

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been a long time since this question was asked. But I find out some resource for later reference.

REST API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/

Python Wrapper:
https://pypi.org/project/appstoreconnect

Answer (score 5):

iTunes com interface documentation is available at http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html

Comment: I've done a google search for this, and it did not provide me with the simple URL you did. Thank you, I've been looking all over for this!

Comment: BTW, Apple appears to have taken down the SDK after releasing iTunes 11 (which in turn breaks important parts of the API).

Answer (score -1):

Run `dir(my_com_client)` to get a list of available methods.

Comment: The win32com wrapper dynamically dispatches methods, so the set cannot be inspected through the usual means like `dir`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Python library to access iTunes API: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-itunes/1.0

Comment: The question was about the COM API used for directly controlling iTunes, while what you have linked here is a wrapper for the Store API.

Comment: You're right! Still the question was:

    "I'm trying to develop some scripts for iTunes in python and actually i'm having quite a hard time getting the API information."

The only mention that could be related to the COM API (instead of Store API) is because of:

    "I'm using the win32com.client module"

that I didn't realize this meant he was willing to use the COM API, instead of the Store one.

(Disclaimer: I never use Windows)